# How to use geckodriver in selenium webdriver 3.0 beta?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I use geckodriver for selenium webdriver 3.0 beta release. When I instantiate firefox like:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//lib//geckodriver");
driver.get("/");
```

I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "pathTogeckodriver");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the code as below, without setting the DesiredCapabilities and it works fine, without any issues

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "pathTogeckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to  define Firefox driver in selenium 3.x series will be:

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Remember this (Selenium 3.x) will also require Jave 8+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "pathToGeckodriver");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

If you put the driver in the same directory as your project you can simply use:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "geckodriver");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

(Or `"geckodriver.exe"` for windows.)